What does なまり mean in this sentence?
すると同じく仕事を終えたあゆみが立ち上がった。動きのない一日の『なまり』をとるように腰を左右に捻ってストレッチをする。
I understand the character is getting up and stretchering after not moving all day but what could  a なまり be?

This なまり means "lead", which is a metal. Or the nominalization of なまる(鈍る), which means "become dull". I think that the author used it as a figurative expression of body stiffness or as a body dullness.
